# jQuery DataTables - Responsive Table head is not working with asp gridview

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, gridview, datatables

The dataTable is work perfect if the window is only one screen size (width). when the screen width is changed, the table head will not resize automatically. Moreover, the above thing is just happening when i set the scrollY property to dataTable. After the scrollY is set, jQuery dataTable will create 2 tables which one for table head and another for table body for scrolling. In my case, the table of table head is not work fine.

image:
[image]

code:

```
    $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').DataTable({
        scrollY: 200,
        scrollX: false,

        columnDefs: [
          {targets: 1 }
        ],

         responsive: true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false
    });
```

any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

change

```
scrollX : false
```

to

```
scrollX : ""
```

Comment: Please elaborate, e.g. explain why it does not work and why your suggestion should.